# NoHostAvailable exception after shutting down nodes of one datacenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am having a cassandra ring across two datacenters, below is the key space definition. when I trying to bring all the nodes of the local datacenter (aws), I am expecting the the datastax driver to query the remote nodes. But in this case I am getting HostNotAvaialble exception.  Please help.

Keyspace definition as below

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS mystore_stress WITH replication = {
   'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
   'sol':2,
   'aws':2
};
```

My session is created as follows:

```
public Session getSession() {
    final Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(contactPoints)
            .withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy("aws", 1)))
            .withReconnectionPolicy(new ExponentialReconnectionPolicy(RECONNECTION_BASE_DELAY, RECONNECTION_MAX_DELAY))
            .withSocketOptions(
                    new SocketOptions()
                            .setConnectTimeoutMillis(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
                            .setReadTimeoutMillis(READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS))
            .withPort(PORT)
            .build();
    return cluster.connect();
}
```

Comment: is there any chance you could take a thread dump and share it?   It's possible you may be running into https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-637.

Comment: Did you shut down all nodes in the aws datacenter before connecting? 
Did you just stop the cassandra service?

Comment: @Roman: I was connected  to aws datacenter and doing continuous http request to my service which posted data to cassandra. I used opscenter to shutdown the nodes

Comment: @Andy: let me try getting the thread dump. thanks for link shared

Comment: @atul - what is the consistency level of your query?

Comment: @Roman, consistency level is default i.e ONE

Comment: If you're using the same session object, then you ideally should be sending data to these hosts, Can you please paste the entire error with the stack trace. It should contain the host IPs that the client is tryuing to connect to. Then make sure you can connect to the hosts in the sol datacenter using these IPs on the cassandra ports.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73706/discussion-between-atul-and-roman-tumaykin).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to review the consistency level on your query. If it's quorum then you should ideally have 3 replicates. You can find some examples of read consistency here:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dmlClientRequestsRead.html

Comment: I suspect this is not the issue, because the driver is not able to supply a connection to make the query on so no query is being made.   If it was a consistency level problem he would be seeing UnavailableException or ReadTimeoutException/WriteTimeoutException.